# array for full calendar

Tags: javascript, php

How should my array look if I want to serialize it and use it in full calendar?

```
(int) 1 => [
    'start_date' => '2016-06-01',
    'end_date' => '2016-06-01'
],
(int) 2 => [
    'start_date' => '2016-06-02',
    'end_date' => '2016-06-02'
],
(int) 3 => [
    'start_date' => '2016-06-03',
    'end_date' => '2016-06-03'
],
(int) 4 => [
    'start_date' => '2016-06-04',
    'end_date' => '2016-06-04'
],
(int) 5 => [
    'start_date' => '2016-06-05',
    'end_date' => '2016-06-05',
    'events' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'date' => 'E',
            'name' => 'holliday'
        ],
        (int) 4 => [
            'date' => 'E',
            'name' => 'holliday'
        ] ] ]
```

This is my array and I use json_encode then send it to the view where i use it on events:  but it seems that is not working...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    // Instantiate fullCalendar
    // ================================
    var date = new Date(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();     

    var jData = $("#JSONdata").html();
    $("#full_calendar").fullCalendar({
        header: {   
            left: "prev,next",
            center: "title",
            right: "today,month,agendaWeek"
        },
        buttonText: {
            prev: "<",
            next: ">"
        },
        editable: true,
        events:jQuery.parseJSON(jData),
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            // content
            var pcontent = '';
            pcontent += '<h5 class=semibold>';
            pcontent += '<img class="mr10" src="/adminre1.2/image/icons/bloggingservices.png" width="42" height="42" />';
            pcontent += calEvent.title;
            pcontent += '</h5>';
            pcontent += '<hr/>';
            pcontent += '<p><span class="ico-clock"></span> Start: ';
            pcontent += $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start).format();
            pcontent += '</p>';
            if (calEvent.end !== null) {
                pcontent += '<p><span class="ico-clock"></span>  End: ';
                pcontent += $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.end).format();
                pcontent += '</p>';
            }

            // bootstrap popover
            $(this).popover({
                placement: 'auto',
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                content: pcontent
            }).popover('toggle');
        }
    });
});
```

```
<div id='JSONdata' style="display:none;"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
```

this is my javascript

Comment: How we should know what your data should be if we are not aware of what is going on on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation is an example for your case:
[FullCalendar Events Array](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/)

The Event object has start and end properties, not start_date and end_date.
.

Comment: if I use events array then I won't need to serialize the array that I'm sending over to the view?

Comment: I solved it. You need to remove the keys so I used array_values()